# converting decimal to binary via java

Tags: java

this code can convert decimal to binary but compiler is checking some error in passing the array to the function

> rishi.java:33: error: incompatible types b[i]=dtob(a[i]); ^ required: int found: void 1 error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Rishi {

    public static void dtob(int n){

            int a[]=new int[25];  
            int binary[] = new int[25];
            int index = 0;

            while(a[n] > 0){

            binary[index++] = a[n]%2;
            a[n] = a[n]/2;

            }

            for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){
            System.out.print(binary[i]+"   ");
            }
       }  

    //enter code here

   public void main(String args[]){

            Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

            int a[]=new int[25];
            int b[]=new int[25];
            int t,i,j;

            for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
                }

            for(i=0;i<5;i++){

                Rishi dtb = new Rishi();//calling 
                b[i]=dtob(a[i]);

                System.out.println(b[i]); 
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error and format your code?

Comment: `new rishi();` is not calling a method, it instantiates a new `rishi` object, hence calling it's constructor, but that's not how you have to call methods. Btw in Java every class should begin with a capital letter, hence if `rishi` is a class it should be `Rishi`.

Comment: i have called a method defined the previous class rishi

Comment: check the line just above code

Comment: rishi.java:33: error: incompatible types
b[i]=dtob(a[i]);
         ^
  required: int
  found:    void
1 error

Comment: The method `dtob()` has a `void` return type, and you're trying to assign the result of it to `b[i]` which should be an `int`.

Comment: Also, you're creating an instance of `Rishi`, but you're never using it...not causing the error, but I don't see the point.

Comment: ya how can i edit my code i.e what possible changes will run this code?

Comment: You do realise that an `int` is a 32-bit value which is in binary already.  It's converting `int` to a decimal which you need the libraries to do. Converting a value which is already binary into binary isn't particularly sane.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code but the reason for getting the error is because you're missing a `return statement` in your `dtob(int n)` method. The type of `dtob(int n)` should be `int` not `void` and also it should return the binary value you are calculating.

Comment: hw can i return the complete binary value